# SQL selection with multiple search fields?

Tags: android, sql

I have a DB “People”, with two columns `NAME` and `RANK`.
I make selection by column `NAME`, with argument “Tom”:

```
db = databaseHelper.open();
userCursor = db.rawQuery(“select *from “ + DatabaseHelper.TABLE + “ where “ + DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_NAME + “ =? “,
new String[] {“Tom”} );
```

And it’s working good.
BUT If I select by both columns `NAME` and `RANK`

```
db = databaseHelper.open();
userCursor=db.rawQuery(“select *from “ + DatabaseHelper.TABLE + “ where “ + DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_NAME + “=?” + “ and “ + DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_RANK + “ =? “,
new String[] {“Tom”, “Junior”} );
```

It doesn’t work.
Where is my fault? Or maybe some advice

Comment: Can you elaborate on "doesn't work"? Are you getting an error? The wrong restul?

Comment: What's your data set like? When you run the first query, does the value of the `RANK` column return `Junior`?

Comment: “Doesn’t work” it’s meen selection with to columns -Listview is empty, when doing selection with one column listview filling with selection by my arg normaly.

Comment: When i make selection by RANK with arg Junior listview filing with data by this selection, when i make with both columns selection listview is empty

Comment: Just to point out there is no space between * and from.  `"select * from "`

Comment: @Red did you tried my given solution?

Answer (score 0):

I find the fault: 
I forgot to add        userCursor.moveToNext();    in the end and put “or” not “and”.

db = databaseHelper.open();
userCursor=db.rawQuery(“select *from “ + DatabaseHelper.TABLE + “ where “ + DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_NAME + “=?” + “ or  “ + DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_RANK + “ =? “,
new String[] {“Tom”, “Junior”} );
userCursor.moveToNext();

Answer (score -1):

try like this it is working for me.
this is normal SQL query and here you can get your result in cursor. after that you can iterate the cursor for data.
here is normal WHERE clause with AND.

```
 public Cursor getDetail(String feed_id, String feed_flag) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE + " WHERE " + DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_NAME + "='" + "Tom" + "' AND " + DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_RANK + "='" + "Junior+ "'", null);
        return c;
    }
```

Comment: I don't know why people blindly De-voting, even this is working code for me.

Comment: @Red Did you try this?

Comment: I can’t adapt your code with my, it have not resolve symbols, method and illegal line end (“‘“, null);

Comment: Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE + " WHERE " + DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_NAME + "='" + "Tom" + "' AND " + DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_RANK + "='" + "Junior+ "'", null);

Comment: I try use only this and it have the same result, empty listview

Comment: You're probably getting downvoted because you're posting a code snippit without explaining **how** it solves OP's issue.

Comment: can you share you create table statment or DB class?